# How do I unit test private controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

What is the best practice to unit-test private methods inside a controller in ASP.NET MVC? The Currently, if I want to unit-test a private method inside a controller I have to set it to public but when I do, that method is exposed to the web.

Is the best way to move the method to a helper class?

Comment: As a side note, you can make public controller actions with the [NonActionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute.aspx) to hide them from the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be moving the method into a helper class that you extracted an interface to. That way it's easier to perform dependency injection and switch the underlaying implementation or mock it if needed.
Testing private methods is a code smell (or a test smell).
Use InternalsVisibleTo trick only when you must (i.e. you are using an untestable class and must raise an event that is hidden from you by a protected function call).

Comment: Thx m8, good to get that confirmed:) Btw what do you mean with "private methods is code smell"?

Comment: @larole: I mean **testing private methods is a code smell**. When you need to test a private method it means that it's either doing too much (and thus violates Separation of Concerns) or too critical that the implementation must be verified. In the first case split the method up to the smallest working subsets of the method so that you may be able to reuse them differently (and thus adhering DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself) and in the second case, create a class that can be injected and test its public methods.

Comment: @larole: Continued: You shouldn't test private methods because the public method that is being tested will fail anyway. Open up google and read about dependency injection & IoC (The holywood principle), SoC, DRY and unit testing private methods.

Comment: Thx, i need to get better using these best practices.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the private object, like this:

```
var privateObject = new PrivateObject(this.controller);
var result = (ActionResult)privateObject.Invoke("RegisterToEvent", shippingAddressID, creditCardID);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could set the method to internal instead of private, and then set the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to the name of your test assembly.

In assembly info:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestAssembly")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an action filter for test methods like this....

```
public class TestActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("loginurl");
         //or throw exception or some other action
    }
}
```

Or you could make the method only publicly accessible to another assembly.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around that problem by limiting tests to *visible* methods. Any private method will be used at least by one *visible* method (otherwise: it can safely be deleted).

So I suggest to develop tests that call the visible methods with practical values so that the private algorithms are tested. If code is not reachable through *visible* methods - delete it.

Comment: Thx for answer. I started doing unittests on visible methods but i felt that i was doing integration tests, not unit tests. I wanted only to test the logic and conditions not input and output.

Comment: @larole - to me it's still unit testing because private methods and methods that use them *have* to be defined on the same *unit*. So the testing is still limited to the (compilation) unit.

Comment: Okey. I just get mixed signals on how to unittest MVC projects. Some say that you should only test if-conditions and logic. Keep the controller and actions simple and move logic out of action/controller and make them testable. Other say test everything...

Comment: @larole - the unit test should demonstrate, that the unit works as specified. Like that methods always return expected values for any input. But as you don't call private methods from outside, it's valid to tweak the unit just to add tests for those methods. If they fail, then some caller should fail too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [PrivateObject](http://www.google.com/search?q=PrivateObject%20Constructor)() method but I like Charlino's suggestion of NonActionAttribute (see comments to original question above), too.